# How to get text defined in xml, after change it programmatically

Tags: android

I have TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Simple Name" />
```

Then I set text programmatically by `amount.setText("other Name")`.
Now, is it possible to get original value from that TextView?
I know that I should use string resources and then there would be no problem but I'm curious is this possible.

Comment: Load your `String` from `Resources` and after changed get it back from same resources...

Comment: Use R.string in you res folder you should have a folder called strings in there defin all your strings and then you can modify them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of getting this value from xml.

1. Put your "Simple Name" to string resources as my_resource
2. Use android:text="@string/my_resource" in your TextView
3. Set text in the code to whatever you want tv.setText("Whatever")
4. Set text in the code back to previous value tv.setText(R.string.my_resource)